# How does MOVSX assembly instruction work?

Tags: assembly, x86, mov

How does the assembly instruction `MOVSX` work in this following example:

```
MOVSX ECX,BYTE PTR DS:[EDX]
```

In this case, here are the state of the registers:

```
ECX = 0000000F   
EDX = 0012FD9F
```

From what I thought, it takes last bytes of [EDX] = 9F, moves it to ECX and then sign extends it to match 16 bits = 0000009F. However, the actual result is 00000016. Can someone help explain where I'm wrong?

Comment: Old question and the answer helps below, but for the people reading this now, you weren't exactly correct here with your sign extension (if this was the correct byte to use). `0x9F = 1001 1111` and therefore, your sign extension bit should be with bit '1' and not bit '0.'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's partially correct. However:

`BYTE PTR DS:[EDX]` obtains the **byte located at the address held in EDX**. This byte is copied to `ECX` into the least significant byte and the rest is filled with the sign of the byte.

For your unexpected result, this means that at the memory address<sup>1</sup> `0x12FD9F` the byte `0x16` is located.

---

Notes:

- the Segment Override Prefix `DS:` isn't necessary here. `[EDX]` automatically refers to `DS`.

---

<sup>1</sup> "memory address" refers to either virtual or physical memory here

Answer (score 5):

Many Intel/AMD x86 instructions are available in "modrm" format - they have two operands, one of which must be a register, the other of which may be a register, or a memory reference, whose address is determined by the modrm byte of the instruction encoding, and possibly by subsequent bytes of the instruction, such as the sib (scaled index byte), and the immediate constant / memory offset.  And also by a possible segment prefix byte.

Usually these are reg,reg/mem instructions, of the form

```
   rsrcdst += rsrc
or
   rsrcdst += Memory[ ... addressessing mode ...]
```

But x86 assembly code does not have separate opcodes / instruction mnemonics for the reg,reg and reg,mem forms of these instructions.  Whether an operand is a register or a memory location is indicated, in the assembler, by assembly syntax.

In this case, your assembly code is

MOVSX ECX,BYTE PTR DS:[EDX]

The instruction opcode is MOVSX.

The destination operand is register ECX.

The source operand is "BYTE PTR DS:[EDX]".   That this is a memory reference is indicated by several things:  (1) the square brackets around "[EDX]" - square brackets are a shorthand for Memory[...address...]. (2) the "DS:" prefix, which indicates that it is in the data segment.  Register operands do not have such a segment prefix.   (3) the "BYTE PTR" - which says "take the memory address specified by 'DS:[EDX]', and interpret it as referencing an 8-bit byte in memory".

I suspect that what you really want is

```
MOVSX ECX,DL
```

"DL" is a name for the low 8 bits of 32-bit register EDX.   I.e. DL=EDX.bits[7:0].  Unfortunately, x86 assemblers usually don;t accept syntax like "EDX.bits[7:0]" (unless I wrote them), so you have to know the historical names of the sub registers:

```
AL = EAX.bits[7:0]
AH = EAX.bits[15:8]
AX = EAX.bits[15:0]
EAX = 32 bit register that "covers" all of the above
```

and so on: BL, CL, DL, DI, ...